# How to put a default value in a dropdown in php?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

My code looks like:

```
<select autofocus="autofocus" name="SourceCountry" id="SourceCountry">
  <?php populate_country();?>
  </select>
```

I am populating all the countries of the world in that dropdown. I want a particular country name(say Japan) as default selected. I am not sure which attribute or property of the select tag does this. Tried to use many, but didnt work out. Can anyone suggest?

The code of populate_country goes like this:

```
if(connect_to_DB()==1)
    $result=FetchCountriesList();
    //mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {       
        echo '<option value='.$row['CountryName'].'>'.$row['CountryName'].'</option>';
     }
```

In FetchCountriesList(), there is a select query like:

SELECT distinct CountryName from Countries

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code of the `populate_country();` function?

Comment: just put the "selected" attribute to the option which contains Japan ...

Comment: The code of populate_country goes like this: 

 if(connect_to_DB()==1)
  $result=FetchCountriesList();
  //mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {  
   echo '<option value='.$row['CountryName'].'>'.$row['CountryName'].'</option>';
     }

In FetchCountriesList(), there is a select query like:

SELECT distinct CountryName from Countries

Comment: @user2811464 add the code of the function to you first post by editing it :)

Comment: Either the question is not clear. Or this is a simple question on HTML. A simple Google search http://www.google.com/search?q=html+select+default+option returns me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your function and try to find Japan and set this one as Selected :)

```
if(connect_to_DB()==1) $result=FetchCountriesList(); 
//mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['CountryName'] !== "Japan") {
        echo '<option value='.$row['CountryName'].'>'.$row['CountryName'].'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value='.$row['CountryName'].' selected="selected">'.$row['CountryName'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant you just put selected not selected="selected"??

Answer (score 0):

Just add attribute `selected="selected"` on the option value that you wish to be selected.

E.g.:

```
<option value="Japan" selected="selected">Japan</option>
```

To use this in your function, replace your function with this:

```
function populate_country($selected = NULL) {

    if(connect_to_DB()==1) $result=FetchCountriesList(); 

    //mysqli_data_seek($result,0); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

        echo '<option value="'.$row['CountryName'].'" '.($selected == $row['CountryName'] ? 'selected="selected"' : NULL).'>'.$row['CountryName'].'</option>';

    }

}
```

You can then use this in your HTML:

```
<select autofocus="autofocus" name="SourceCountry" id="SourceCountry">
  <?php populate_country("Japan");?>
  </select>
```

Comment: I think he understands the selected thing, but he doesn't know where to add it as the content comes from a php funtion..

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear: "I am not sure which attribute or property of the select tag does this."

Comment: Hi Emilian, am not able to add selected attribute.... here am fetching many country names dynamically.. i have written just one option tag to fetch all the country names

Answer (score 0):

Add the `seleteced` attribute, e.g.:

```
<option value="test" selected="selected">Bla</option>
```

```
$defValue = 'Japan';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<option value="' . $row['CountryName'] . '"';
  if ($row['CountryName'] === $defValue) {
    echo ' selected="selected"';
  }
  echo '>';
  echo $row['CountryName'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Change "seleteced" to "selected", bro.

Comment: I think he understands the selected thing, but he doesn't know where to add it as the content comes from a php funtion..

Comment: Hi ComFreek, i have not written multiple <option> statements for all the individual values. I am fetching the country names through MYSQL and its getting populated in a drop down. I am calling a function in PHP to populate the country names.

Comment: @EmilianManolache To be honest, I lost my whole answer two times!

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `selected`. Try this:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="kor">Korea</option>
    <option value="rus">Russia</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="jap">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think he understands the selected thing, but he doesn't know where to add it as the content comes from a php funtion..

Comment: @JoranDenHouting a part of the question: `I am not sure which attribute or property of the select tag does this`. So I think the question was about attribute :)

Answer (score 0):

Add selected for your option in your function populate_country(). (in the option you want to select as default only)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option> Red </option>
    <option selected="selected"> blue </option>
    <option> yellow </option>
</select>
```

Blue would be the selected in that dropdown.

Basically you need to loop throught your values and match if the value you want matches with the ones you have, and add the `selected="selected"` string to that option:

I would do something like this: (untested)

```
function populate_country($country){
    $countries = array('algeria', 'japan', 'mexico', 'united kingdom' ..... );
    foreach($countries as $country){
        $selected = (strtolower($selected) == $country) ? ' selected="selected"' : null;
        echo "<option$selected>".ucwords($country)."</option>\r\n";
    }
}
```